# MS-Access Joining 2 Subqueries

Tags: ms-access

Need a little help with subqueries

If I have a 1 query like this:

```sql
SELECT Learner.Learner_Id, Max(LearnerEmploymentStatus.DateEmpStatApp) AS LatestEmpDate, Learner.LearnRefNumber, Learner.FamilyName, Learner.GivenNames, EmploymentStatusMonitoring.ESMType
FROM (Learner LEFT JOIN LearnerEmploymentStatus ON LearnerEmploymentStatus.Learner_Id = LearnerEmploymentStatus.Learner_Id) LEFT JOIN EmploymentStatusMonitoring ON LearnerEmploymentStatus.LearnerEmploymentStatus_Id = EmploymentStatusMonitoring.LearnerEmploymentStatus_Id
WHERE EmploymentStatusMonitoring.ESMType="BSI"
GROUP BY Learner.Learner_Id, Learner.LearnRefNumber, Learner.FamilyName, Learner.GivenNames, EmploymentStatusMonitoring.ESMType
```

...and another like this:

```sql
SELECT Learner.Learner_Id, LearnerEmploymentStatus.DateEmpStatApp, EmploymentStatusMonitoring.ESMCode
FROM (Learner LEFT JOIN LearnerEmploymentStatus ON Learner.Learner_Id = LearnerEmploymentStatus.Learner_Id) LEFT JOIN EmploymentStatusMonitoring ON LearnerEmploymentStatus.LearnerEmploymentStatus_Id = EmploymentStatusMonitoring.LearnerEmploymentStatus_Id
```

...and I wanted to do a join between the 2 queries (LEFT JOIN on the common `Learner_Id` and `LatestEmpDate` / `DateEmpStatApp` fields), how would I go about doing all this work in a single query where the 2 queries above would be subqueries?

My attempt below is not being accepted (JOIN expression not supported):

```sql
SELECT sQ1.Learner_Id, sQ1.LearnRefNumber, sQ1.FamilyName, sQ1.GivenNames, sQ1.LatestEmpDate, sQ1.ESMType, sQ2.ESMCode
FROM
(SELECT Learner.Learner_Id, Max(LearnerEmploymentStatus.DateEmpStatApp) AS LatestEmpDate, Learner.LearnRefNumber, Learner.FamilyName, Learner.GivenNames, EmploymentStatusMonitoring.ESMType
FROM (Learner LEFT JOIN LearnerEmploymentStatus ON LearnerEmploymentStatus.Learner_Id = LearnerEmploymentStatus.Learner_Id) LEFT JOIN EmploymentStatusMonitoring ON LearnerEmploymentStatus.LearnerEmploymentStatus_Id = EmploymentStatusMonitoring.LearnerEmploymentStatus_Id
WHERE EmploymentStatusMonitoring.ESMType="BSI"
GROUP BY Learner.Learner_Id, Learner.LearnRefNumber, Learner.FamilyName, Learner.GivenNames, EmploymentStatusMonitoring.ESMType) As sQ1
LEFT JOIN
(SELECT Learner.Learner_Id, LearnerEmploymentStatus.DateEmpStatApp, EmploymentStatusMonitoring.ESMCode
FROM (Learner LEFT JOIN LearnerEmploymentStatus ON Learner.Learner_Id = LearnerEmploymentStatus.Learner_Id) LEFT JOIN EmploymentStatusMonitoring ON LearnerEmploymentStatus.LearnerEmploymentStatus_Id = EmploymentStatusMonitoring.LearnerEmploymentStatus_Id) As sQ2
ON (sQ1.Learner_Id = sQ2.Learner_Id) AND (sQ1.LatestEmpDate = sQ2.DateEmpStatApp);
```

Comment: Do the 2 queries execute ok independently? The joins in the 1st (at least) look a little messed up

Comment: Ahh yes, must've mistakenly changed that afterwards when I was copying/pasting. Works without error, but not the query result I was looking for.. back to the drawing board I guess

Answer (score 0):

Would something like this get you what you want...?

```
SELECT l.Learner_Id, d.LatestEmpDate, l.LearnRefNumber, l.FamilyName, l.GivenNames, m.ESMType, m.ESMCode
FROM ((Learner AS l
  LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT s.Learner_Id, MAX(s.DateEmpStatApp) AS LatestEmpDate
    FROM LearnerEmploymentStatus AS s
    GROUP BY s.Learner_Id) AS d ON d.Learner_Id = l.Learner_Id)
  LEFT JOIN LearnerEmploymentStatus AS ls ON (ls.Learner_Id = d.Learner_Id) AND (ls.DateEmpStatApp = d.LatestEmpDate))
  LEFT JOIN EmploymentStatusMonitoring AS m ON m.LearnerEmploymentStatus_Id = ls.LearnerEmploymentStatus_Id
WHERE m.ESMType = 'BSI'
```

Assumes the same learner won't have the same `DateEmpStatApp` twice, which may or not be valid.